# C#: Check if type T is bool

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I can't believe I can't google this. I don't know what to google.

```
public static T GetValue<T>(T defaultValue)
{
  if (T is bool) // <-- what is the correct syntax here?
    return (T)true; // <-- I don't think this works either
}
```

EDIT: Sorry I didn't mention, the function above is only to show my question. It's not a real function. Thanks everyone for the answers!

Comment: Try searching for the compiler errors. I am sure there are many duplicates. At the very least, *include* [compiler] errors in questions when applicable.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If one *must* use this same method/signature and *must* use the type of `T` (and there *are* reason for such, although if there are not then see Albin's answer):

```
public static T GetValue<T>(T defaultValue)
{
  // Need to use typeof to get a Type object for bool, just as with T
  if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool)) {
    // Need to say "get out of my way C#"
    // The first cast to object is required as true (bool) is
    // otherwise not castable to an unrestricted T.
    // This widen-restrict approach could result in a cast error,
    // but from the above check it is known that T is bool.
    return (T)(object)true;
  }
  // .. other stuff that .. does stuff.
}
```

However, explicitly returning `true` (which is not the default value for a boolean) and ignoring `defaultValue` entirely otherwise seems .. suspect. But - [*It compiles! Ship it!*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/48448)

Notes:

- The use `==` for Types will *not work reliably* for subclasses (but it's okay because `bool` is a structure so subtypes are not an issue). In those cases, look at `IsAssignableFrom`.
- `typeof(T)` is not necessarily the type of the value passed in (which could be `null` for reference types). This, along with subtypes, can lead to subtle variations to approaches that use `is` on the value.

Comment: +1 for pointing the issue of this solution for subtypes. I spent hours on such an issue once.

Answer (score 15):

Don't check the type, check the variable

```
public static T GetValue<T>(T defaultValue)
{
  if (defaultValue is bool) // <-- what is the correct syntax here?
    return (T)true;
}
```

But just as a side not, when you do type checking and have different handling for different types in a generic type you are typically doing something wrong.

Why don't you create an overload for the types with special handling?

```
public static bool GetValue(bool defaultValue)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, but I've got this function which is already working for all string/int/double/float/decimal except bool

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are looking for `default(T)`, which returns default value for provided type. Default value for `bool` is `false`.